# Neo4j 2.0.4 support for "LOAD CSV FROM" command

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm using neo4j 2.0.4 version currently. Earlier i was using neo4j 2.1.2 version . I downgraded the neo4j version from 2.1.2 to 2.0.4 as I'm not able to import the data from MySQL to neo4j using batch import.

Now I'm using Neo4j 2.0.4. When i tried to load the csv file into noe4j using like `LOAD CSV FROM "file:D:\\Neo4\\try.csv" AS emp ...` , it's throwing an error  as below

```
Invalid input 'L': expected <init> (line 1, column 1)
"LOAD CSV FROM "file:D:\\Neo4\\try.csv" AS emp"
```

When i tried the same query using neo4j 2.1.2 , it is running properly and showing the proper graph.

So is it like 2.0.4 does not support `LOAD CSV FROM`  command ?
What needs to be done to get the proper output without error in 2.0.4?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think LOAD CSV was introduced in version 2.1

https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/releases/tag/2.1.1

Comment: thank you. It's true that LOAD CSV is a 2.1 feature and can't be used in 2.0 version.